# How to reduce the complexity of convex hull of moving points?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, time-complexity, convex-hull, code-complexity

I have implemented the convex hull algorithm for N randomly generated points. As per my requirement, I am advancing this. In those N points, K points will change their positions. I have to calculate convex hull again. I am just recomputing the convex hull again. But this is taking so much time (high complexity). Since I have already one hull, and some of those only moving points. Can I use this property anyway and is there any possibility to reduce the complexity of this problem?

Comment: All of the `N` points may not be needed to form the hull. Say `N1` points (`N1 <= N`) are responsible to form hull. Are these `N1` points only your moving points?

Comment: This is a simpler form of [Dynamic convex Hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_convex_hull) as you only need updates. Would recommend looking for an already available implementation

Comment: No. Total N points are there. Let say N1 of those are useful to form the hull. Out of all points, K ( k<=N)  points are moving. These K may be inside the hull or may be on the boundary of the hull (belongs to those N1).

Comment: If you store your N points in a quadtree, you can determine in ~O(log n) time for each one whether it's a boundary point or not. When recalculating the hull, you can just check if the ones moved have become part of or been removed from the hull.